# What is the combo in this bag-work video?

Tags: boxing

I'm learning boxing combos. I want to copy his combo in this [video](https://www.instagram.com/p/B0_I8p_hbaU/), but my brain is too slow to see it. Can you tell me the complete sequence in that video?

Comment: Why do you want to copy a heavy bag workout? It's just a lot of jabs and crosses, with some hook shots thrown in here and there. What purpose do you think will be served by memorizing someone else's workout?

Comment: To look cool. I'm new to boxing. I also think those combos are effective to train hand speed. I can't just throw like a complete idiot at the gym. Better copy a good boxer.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for a downvote.

Comment: @ΗλεκτρολόγοςΜηχανικός Down votes are anonymous for good reasons, mostly to avoid abuse being thrown about. It is more or less trivial to spot what the boxer does provided that you have a limited amount of knowledge of boxing. If you do not, you should not attempting to mimic this workout as you might get injured. Note that I have not downvoted you, so it's just guesses. As far as I can tell this is not a bad question (no down vote) but neither is it a good one (no up vote). It might be improved by asking how to get those skills in the first place or about similar workouts for beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my take on it might not be 100%

```
lj=left jab, rc=right cross, lh=left hook
```

- (lj,rc) x3 (coming forward)
- (step back) lj, rc
- (lj,rc) x6 (coming forward)
- (coming forward) (lj,rc) x3, rc
- step back (lj, rc)
- lh x3 (body)
- step back big wind up
- lh (body)
- (rc,lj) x2, rc (defensive)
- double jab
- lj,rc,lj,
- retreating jab

He's pretty fast and getting a good workout but you might think about his lack of head movement.  If I soak up a left hook, I'm straight back with my right hand so he should think about head movement and keeping that left hand up.

I like bag work and getting good combos going, but it depends on where the bag ends up, whether it's swung away from you or is moving laterally so trying to memorise combos more than about 5-7 moves is not really practical, and you'll just be repeating other shorter combos. While I'm here, my favorite combos on the bag:

1. jab, cross, lh, rc
2. jab,cross, lh (body), lh(head), rc (stepping back)
3. trying to get a perfect jab cross (so elusive, as I do mean perfect)
4. jab, massive swinging haymaker for the sheer fun of it
5. jab, cross, jab, spinning backfist (because I'm not a boxer) :)